# Why quantity_and_stock_status is always 1 in /V1/products?searchCriteria in Magento-2.2.7?

Tags: product, rest-api, magento2.2.7, search-criteria

I am using Magento-2.2.7 . If i call this endpoint /V1/products?searchCriteria , it always show each product having same quantity_and_stock_status . Whenever product is in_stock or out_of_stock it always show quantity_and_stock_status:1. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Please give me solution for that problen.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the admin panel setting in:

Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options > **Display Out of Stock Products**

If this is set to **NO**, only products that are in stock will be returned.